# how to keep an item focused in c# listview?

Tags: c#, listview

i'm trying to keep the last pressed item highlighted in the listview, anyone know how can i do it?

Answer (score 19):

I'm assuming you want to keep the selected item highlighted when the control loses focus.
Then you should check out the [HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) property.

Comment: Tweak your monitor so you can see the light-gray background.

Comment: i'll try to explain again... i have a listview without items in the begining.. when i add an item, i want it to be defaultly highlighted in blue, and when i'm clicking the mouse not on an item but still in the listview, i want that the last highlighted item to remain highlighted... in other words, there always be an item highlighted if there is one

Comment: @RoyGavrielov - some years passed... what you need is to programmatically select it lv.Items[0].Selected=true

Comment: Unlike the ListBox control when focus is moved to another control the selected items do not maintain their blue highlighted colors but change to a light grey. If your ListView backcolor is also light, which it is by default then the selected rows are hard to see. An easy solution is to change the ListView backcolor to a slightly darker color. Also you can use ListView.Focus() after moving to another control, although if the other control is say a TextBox that isn't a good solution but its good for buttons etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and change the selected index/item to the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use [ListView::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx)  for that. Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/aee95fe6-2d91-4637-b5e7-4ebd3283991e) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the code example here: [List view Highlight selected.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915643/list-view-highlight-selected/15750074)
 It shows how to set the foreground/background color of the listview selected item when you change focus away from the listview control.